# Can't connect MySQL with my piwigo app on railway.app

Tags: sql, mysql, database, docker, railway

I wanna deploy my Piwigo project my on railway.app and I did 2 instances

1. An instance of MySQL
2. An instance of my repo that contains only a Dockerfile

[image]

Here's the content of this Docker file
**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine:3.10.3
LABEL maintainer="Moritz Heiber <hello@heiber.im>"
      
ENV PIWIGO_VERSION="12.2.0" \
      PIWIGO_CHECKSUM="824ee83f46654b68962263567f2957933d75b2bac016e6dbb9ea9df9a2a86e88"
      
RUN set -x && apk --no-cache add curl php7 php7-gd php7-mysqli php7-json php7-session php7-exif && \
      curl -Lo /tmp/piwigo.zip "http://piwigo.org/download/dlcounter.php?code=${PIWIGO_VERSION}" && \
      echo "${PIWIGO_CHECKSUM}  /tmp/piwigo.zip" | sha256sum -wsc - && \
      adduser -h /piwigo -DS piwigo && \
      unzip /tmp/piwigo.zip -d /piwigo && \
      install -d -o piwigo /piwigo/piwigo/galleries /piwigo/piwigo/upload && \
      chown -R piwigo /piwigo/piwigo/local && \
      apk --no-cache del curl && \
      rm /tmp/piwigo.zip
      
WORKDIR /piwigo
USER piwigo
      
CMD ["php","-S","0.0.0.0:8000","-t","piwigo"]
```

In the MySQL database, here's the credentials

- **MYSQL_URL:** mysql://root:WtcQge40zvgaTaksreDT@containers-us-west-153.railway.app:7305/railway
- **MYSQLDATABASE** railway
- **MYSQLHOST** containers-us-west-153.railway.app
- **MYSQLPASSWORD** WtcQge40zvgaTaksreDT
- **MYSQLPORT** 7305
- **MYSQLUSER** root

[image]

In the piwigo side, I tried to put all informations from the database
and it gives me this an error saying **Cannot connect to server** [image]

Answer (score 1):

So the application is able to reach the MySQL server, but it is not able to connect to the database.
Assuming the database is created, and the credentials are correct, I would check the connection string, which should be in the following format:

```
mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database_name
```

In your case, it seems like the connection string you are using has the `database_name` as `railway`, but you mentioned you tried to switch to `piwigo_mysql` as the database name. Make sure to update the connection string accordingly.

IE.: If your username is `root`, the password is `Mypassword`, the hostname is `containers-us-west-103.railway.app`, the port is `5576`, and the database name is `piwigo_mysql`, then your connection string should look like this:

```
mysql://root:Mypassword@containers-us-west-103.railway.app:5576/piwigo_mysql
```

Also, since you are using Railway, remember that Railway automatically injects [environment variables](https://docs.railway.app/databases/mysql) for the provisioned databases into your deployed environments, which you can use in your application. Make sure you are correctly using these environment variables to connect to your MySQL database.

- `MYSQLHOST`
- `MYSQLPORT`
- `MYSQLUSER`
- `MYSQLPASSWORD`
- `MYSQLDATABASE`
- `MYSQL_URL`

These environment variables should be available to your Docker container in the Railway environment. Make sure your application is configured to use them. If your application expects the database connection details to be in a different format or under different environment variable names, you might need to add some additional configuration or code to your application to correctly use the Railway environment variables.

These variables will be automatically set to the correct values for the MySQL server you provisioned. You can use these in your code to construct the connection string dynamically, which would be a more secure practice.

Comment: It didn't work

mysql -hcontainers-us-west-183.railway.app -uroot -Mypassword --port 6764 --protocol=TCP railway

I putted 
Host: containers-us-west-183.railway.app
User: Root
Password: Mypassword
database railway

Comment: @SpicyyRiice Did you get the same error message? The MySQL command you've provided seems to be incorrect. The password flag `-p` is missing before the password itself. `mysql -hcontainers-us-west-183.railway.app -uroot -pMypassword --port=6764 --protocol=TCP railway`

Comment: Nono this is from the railway that provide me the command

It's not working

Comment: @SpicyyRiice Do you have an error message? Why railway would display a command which is false? (without the `-p`)

Comment: It says "Cannot connect to server" on Piwigo page

Comment: @SpicyyRiice OK. Can you edit your question with the full context (what was typed, the full output with error message, and the environment variables)?

Comment: It's now edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253956/discussion-between-vonc-and-spicyyriice).